# nodejs POST 500 error

Tags: node.js, rest, post, http-post, node-request

I am using request module from node js to make a post call to other api, which throw 500 error

```
accessTokenStep2 : (obj,env,email,password) => {

    console.log(obj);

    let transId = obj.transid;
    let csrfId = obj.csrfId;
    let app = env.getAppUrl();
    let tenant = env.getTenantId();
    let policy = env.getPolicy();
    let url2 = ("https://" + app + "/" + tenant + "/" + policy + "/SelfAsserted?tx=" + transId + "&p=" + policy);



    var options= {
        'request_type'   : 'RESPONSE',
        "signInName" : '************',
        "password" : '******',
        "g-recaptcha-response-toms" : "03AEHxwuy8mq_8jbEWU--XHGea2dF-p7F-oUmZhAgpr1Xt7XyyrzBQpJZJilwhJZPG3D-K_HldpTEEl_2Xi51xm4ICCg6-w66XfR5nE1-Cj39ytH6QZiY2yJUTy-1CJZ6qNfJBsO7EG2Kba7cSGhQgetkhAxJOBtI-FJt5WlRdjP6UHgId11rSVhSCS2kphf1Z-BO62Fu2Jm6jWxnbTiVceEVXuQTOEibtQnQ-n2ckOLI-i0GI1tFBAVi6Lu6NZkQII7m_00ZyJtSoik-1LCNNQ8GXmOxFnnVTnvm-vr3mk_RmNaLS9CT6eGlo0CfpK3DiVTLEArQDTuxY"
    };

    var headers = {
          'User-Agent'          :  'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:46.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/46.0',
          'Content-Type'        : 'application/xml',
          'Accept'              : 'application/json, text/javascript, **/*//*; q=0.01',
          'X-Requested-With'    : 'XMLHttpRequest',
          'X-CSRF-TOKEN'        : csrfId
        };




 return new Promise( (resolve, reject) => {

     request({
        url: url2,
        headers:headers,
        method: "POST", 
        form: options           
      }, function(error, response, body){

         // console.log(error);
          console.log("status code" + response.statusCode);
         (response.statusCode == 200 ? resolve(body) : reject(error));
    });

 });

}
```

I have tried passing the data through all the available properties like  form,formData,body along with json true and json property.

But still throughs 500 error.

Comment: Can you share the third party API end point details with me? so that I can cross check your implementation

Comment: if the call get succeeded it will return status code object as {'status' : 200}

Comment: Is the 3rd Party API fine? Have you tried hitting that using postman?
Where are you checking the 500 error.
Try printing whole response and then Debug. That might help.

Comment: yes 3rd party is working well, I have tried executing same from java code base it is working very well retruns the data.

I am checking the response.status from my command